# Nearest value of a given value

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Given this pandas Series.

`x = pd.Series([5, 10])`

I use searchsorted and a loop to find the closest value of the looped number, X.

```
for X in xrange(1, 11):
    print X, x.searchsorted(X)
```

What is returned.

```
1 [0]
2 [0]
3 [0]
4 [0]
5 [0]
6 [1]
7 [1]
8 [1]
9 [1]
10 [1]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is having 6 and 7 return `[0]` because those numbers are closer to 5 than 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `.searchsorted()` you could also check for the `index` of the `pd.Series` value that minimizes the `absolute` difference to the value in question:

```
import numpy as np
for X in range(1, 11):
    print(X, (np.abs(x - X)).argmin())

1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 1
9 1
10 1
```